# Why browser refresh does not display latest changes?

Tags: reactjs

I am learning reactjs and I started the server `npm start` then I typed these code in index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class StorePicker extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return <p>Hello</p>
    }
}

render(<StorePicker/>, document.querySelector('#main'));
```

When I change "hello" to something else and refresh the browser nothing get changed !! what is the problem ?

Index.html

```
<div id="main">

</div>
```

Comment: what does your `index.html` file look like?

Comment: try opening the page in an incognito window.

Comment: @JaredMenard same problem I always get old value unless I restart the server !!

Comment: are you using `create-react-app`?

Comment: @illiteratewriter no I just used the example in the tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to configure your server for hot reloading for the content to change in the browser as you change the code. You can use [react-hot-loader](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader) plugin in case you are not using any hot reloading plugin or you can use [webpack-dev-server](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server) with hot reloading.

Since you are starting out I will highly recommend you use [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app). `create-react-app` comes with hot reloading.

To install `create-react-app` globally, run `npm install -g create-react-app` on terminal then run `create-react-app my-app` where `my-app` is your app name.

If you've latest version of node just run each of these

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

on the terminal

Comment: download the `create-react-app` then run `npx create-react-app my-app` ?

Comment: I've added that to the answer. `npx` is for latest version of `npm`

Comment: thanks I have latest version of node but I get these errors https://imgur.com/a/txw2m please advise

Comment: there's no image

Comment: did you try `npx create-react-app my-app`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167896/discussion-between-illiteratewriter-and-wel).

Comment: seems like a firewall problem !